# How to modify Elementor wordpress post from php?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, elementor

I need to change some elementor post contents in batch.
As a first test I'm trying to just copy the content from another post like that:

```
//copy the standard post content (maybe useless?)
$current_content = get_the_content($postIDtocopy);
wp_update_post(array( 'ID' => $postIDtooverwrite,  'post_content' => $current_content )); 

//copy the elementor content
$elementor_data = get_post_meta( $postIDtocopy, '_elementor_data', true );
update_post_meta( $postIDtooverwrite, '_elementor_data', $elementor_data );

//force cache update
wp_cache_post_change($postIDtooverwrite);
```

But the resulting post is just blank after that. What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: You are passing a post id as first parameter to `get_the_content`, but that is not what this function expects in that position. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: I'm also in the same situation. I managed to view the page content using the info from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307783/echoing-elementor-page-content-in-template-but-it-doesnt-get-styles-and-some-w. Have you figured out how to save the content yet?